# overloading assignment operator doesn't work with chaining c++

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

main.cpp :

Simple2DMatrix &Simple2DMatrix::assign (const Simple2DMatrix &matrixB)
{

```
if ((numRows == matrixB.numRows)
    && (numCols == matrixB.numCols)
    )
{

    for (int r = 0; r < numRows; r++)
    {
        for (int c = 0; c < numCols; c++)
        {
            this->setElement(r, c, matrixB.getElement(r, c));
        }
    }
    return (*this);
}
else

{
    throw "Dimensions does not match!";
}
```

}

and addition as:

```
  if ((this->numRows == matrixB.numRows)
    && (this->numCols == matrixB.numCols)
    )
{

    for (int r = 0; r < this->numRows; r++)
    {
        for (int c = 0; c < this->numCols; c++)
        {
            this->setElement(r, c, this->getElement(r, c) + matrixB.getElement(r, c));
        }
    }
    return (*this);
}
else

{
    throw " Dimensions does not match!";
}
```

therefore, assignment will be:
{

```
if ((numRows == matrixB.numRows)
    && (numCols == matrixB.numCols)
    )
{

    for (int r = 0; r < numRows; r++)
    {
        for (int c = 0; c < numCols; c++)
        {
            this->setElement(r, c, matrixB.getElement(r, c));
        }
    }
    return (*this);
}
else

{
    throw "Dimensions does not match!";
}
```

}

and in the header for operator+ :

```
    Simple2DMatrix<T> matrixTemp(matrixA.numRows, matrixA.numCols);

    matrixTemp.sum(matrixA, matrixB);
    return (matrixTemp);
```

and for operator= :

```
this->assign(matrixB);
return(*this);
```

thank you very much for all your msgs.

Comment: Sure you're not trying to assign a `const` object of `Simple2DMatrix`? Show how you call the assignment operator in your question please!

Comment: Also relevant: the `+` operator, the assignment, and the *complete* error message. Most likely is that your addition operator has a bad return type.

Comment: You really should put more of your code there, and mark exactly **where** you are receiving the error message, otherwise we can't help you...

Comment: You should not split templates into header and source, write it all in the header.

Comment: Your addition (operator +) is likely messed up

Comment: what if the order of matrix A is not equal to the order of matrix B+C?

Comment: @Massa  I updated my post . thank you very much for all your msgs

Comment: what is matrixA in your addition operator??

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Thank you for adding more code, but please notice that in adding code, you *removed any description of the problem*. Please put it back. And if you think the problem is with your overloading of the assignment operator, take care to include the assignment-operator code in your question.

Answer (score 2):

here is your code of( operator +) :

```
if ((this->numRows == matrixB.numRows)
    && (this->numCols == matrixB.numCols)
    )
{

    for (int r = 0; r < matrixA.numRows; r++)
    {
        for (int c = 0; c < matrixA.numCols; c++)
        {
            this->setElement(r, c, matrixA.getElement(r, c) + matrixB.getElement(r, c));
        } //what is matrixA?
    }
    return (*this); //what you want to return?? it seems you are doing B=B+C
}
else

{
    throw " Dimensions does not match!";
}
```

actually you need to first create a temporary object of your class and store addition of
B and C in it.
then return that temp variable.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. Well actually i edited this part. there is no matrixA in this part of addition. I would like to pass the result just like A = B +C ; B + C works fine but when it comes to pass by operator=, the error received = " no match for operator=. the funny thing is that when i use operator== instead of operator= definition it passes the results well! @Bramsh

Comment: perhaps there is some problem with the prototype of your operator overloading function.

Comment: you guess so? how can i fix it then?  I have no idea how to solve it!

Comment: well mine is simply defined as :                      Simple2DMatrix<T> operator=  (const Simple2DMatrix<T> &matrixB); which T is defined by template in my case is double.    @Bramsh

Comment: check is it same in .h file and in .cpp file, usually it happens that there is only mistake of capital letter or something like this.

Comment: looks same! Do you think template can cause any problems ? @Bramsh